# Firebase storage React Native upload undefined image

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-storage, react-native-firebase

I am working on a React Native application with Firebase and Expo, and I am facing issues with undefined image in firebase storage.

I am using Firebase Storage to store my images, and I have implemented the image upload feature in my application but when I look in my storage my images only weigh 9 bytes and when I open them only one word appears: undefined.

Here is how I upload it :

```
const pickImage = async () => {
    let image = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [4, 3],
      quality: 1,
    });

if (!image.canceled) {
      setImage(image.assets[0].uri);
    }

const addPost = async (data) => {
if (image) {
const imageRef = ref(storage, `images/${auth.currentUser.uid}/${Date.now()}`;
image, {
         contentType: 'image/jpeg',
       });
)
const response = await uploadBytesResumable(imageRef, image);
```

here is my firebase storage :

[image: my firebase storage]

I have checked Firebase Storage rules, and ensured proper authentication.

I think the problem come from the

```
const response = await uploadBytesResumable(imageRef, image);
```

I've tried with just 'uploadBytyes' but I have : ReferenceError : Property 'uploadBytes' doesn't exist.

Has anyone encountered this issue before and have suggestions on how to resolve it?